# Help with this Caml Query ? Use in SharePoint Add-In

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, caml

I'm using this caml query in order to receive only the item with title "Full Day"

```
CamlQuery getFullDayHoursQuery = new CamlQuery();

                getFullDayHoursQuery.ViewXml =
                    @"<View>

                                <Where>
                                    <And>
                                    <Eq>
                                        <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
                                        <Value Type = 'Text'>Full Day</Value>
                                    </Eq>
                                    </And>
                                </Where>

                           </View>";

                ListItemCollection getFullDayHoursItem = durationSettings.GetItems(getFullDayHoursQuery);
```

I keep getting all the items of the list returned . I tried to change it by adding 'Full Days' or "Full Days" but the Caml Query helper always return me all the results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
var employeeList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Employees");
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml
                         (
                          "<View>" +
                              "<Query>" +
                                  "<Where>" +
                                        "<Eq>" +
                                            "<FieldRef Name=\"EmpNickName\"/>" +
                                            "<Value Type=\"Text\">" + loginName + "</Value>" +
                                        "</Eq>" +
                                  "</Where>" +
                              "</Query>" +
                               "<RowLimit>1</RowLimit>" +
                         "</View>"
                       );

var items = employeeList.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(items, "Include(ID, Title)");
```

Comment: Actually it worked when i used the LinkTitle field instead of the Title field.

Comment: Please, accept the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to use this code :

```
string fullDayOption = "Full Day";

                getFullDayHoursQuery.ViewXml =
                    @"<View>
                            <Query>
                                <Where>

                                    <Eq>
                                        <FieldRef Name='LinkTitle'/>
                                        <Value Type = 'Computed'>" + fullDayOption + @"</Value>
                                    </Eq>

                                </Where>
                           </Query>
                           </View>";
```